# How do I set up the libraries correctly for Windows' GDI in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, libraries

I want to make a C++ program that has live access to the pixels (colors and intensity e.g. bitmap) on the screen. One of the ways I think that should be possible is using Windows' GDI functions such as [CreateCompatibleDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatibledc).

The problem is that when I try to run it, I get error message: 
"
C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Temp\cce0hZ9w.o   Screencapture_example.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateCompatibleDC'
"

So it looks like the library containing the function is not present or not included. However I did include windows.h and wingdi.h, and according to the page in the link given above, the function is part of wingdi.h.

It also says it requires library Gdi32.lib which I can't find anywhere on my computer. However there is a file called libgdi32.a, which sits in the folder C:\Programfiles\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib. I downloaded the gdi32.lib and added it to the same folder. The error message is unchanged when I recompile.

That folder is included in the libraries section of the Dev-C++ editor, which uses the gcc compiler. My operating system is Windows 10.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<wingdi.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL); // get the desktop device context
HDC hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // create a device context to use yourself

//More to come here but I don't want to complicate it too much before
//I get it to work this far.

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to create a program using mingw and gcc, then following instructions that are meant to be followed with Visual Studio and Windows SDK...

Comment: @yms So the problem is that it doesn't work with the gcc compiler? Do I have to use Visual Studio to make it work?

Comment: As you identified you should use the library `libgdi32.a`.  The documentation to use `Gdi32.lib` is for the MSVC tool-chain.  As you are using the MinGW64 tool-chain (which uses gcc) you need to adjust the library names accordingly.  When new to developing on a platform it is often easier to use the native tool-chains as all the supporting documentation matches what you need to do.

Comment: @ Richard  Is it enough to link to the folder which the file sits in, or do I need to link to the file directly? About the tool-chain: Until now everything I did in C++ worked well with the gcc compiler, so I wasn't aware that there would be differences other than how the editor looks.

Comment: You need to link with the file directly.  Basically MinGW64 is a port of gcc to the MS-Windows environment with reverse engineering of MS's WinAPI supporting libraries.  gcc because of it's Linux background expects libraries to be in a different format, with different naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

The header files only provide declarations, For CreateCompatibleDC you need to provide gdi32.lib as part of the link (this is the "Library" portion of the Requirements block on Microsoft documentation pages).

Comment: I downloaded the gdi32.lib and added it to the folder C:\Programfiles\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib. The error message is unchanged when I recompile.